# Speech to text Conversion Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am new to python and want to convert  speech to text using python libraries.But not using APIs.Basically,I want my code to run without internet too.Which library I should use?I have learned SpeechRecognition is the simplest one but I see in every use case it makes use of an API.Please suggest how should I proceed.

Comment: try https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pyttsx3 module. It stands for Python Text To Speech version 3.

you can check out my GitHub repo to learn about the use of speech recognition and pyttsx3.

https://github.com/shuvampaul2005/J.A.R.V.I.S